# What does the "Decouple app installation for realtime updates from page tab app installation" migration do?

Tags: facebook

We just received an email telling us that our facebook app needs to enable the "Decouple app installation for realtime updates from page tab app installation." migration because it is going to be set to "on" for everyone in a couple weeks, however, I can't find anything about what that migration actually does (the only article i could find that mentions it: https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/1092/using-the-facebook-20-plugin/page-3 only says "leave it off if you don't know what this means".

Our app posts to the user feed and/or page feed of our clients

So anyone here knows what this migration entails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, when a page tab app is added to a page a real-time subscription is added too. What the migration does is to not add the real-time subscription when the page tab app is added. Instead you have to call the API if you want to setup a real-time subscription.

If you don't use real-time subscriptions the migration will not affect you at all.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with subscription? We also have this warning and we are using the realtime. We have a realtime subscription, when a user adds our app we install it on the tab as

```
        FacebookClient client = getFacebookClient(pageId);
        String response = client.publish(pageId+"/tabs", String.class, Parameter.with("app_id", channel.getApi_token()));
```

As I understood it when we wrote this code way back, this enables the single page for the realtime on the application?